# Как быстро обработать большой .csv?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Есть `train.csv` в 3млн+ строк состоящий из столбцов `user_id`, `cart`.

[image: Таблица из .csv]

В зависимости от значений в двух этих столбцах необходимо сформировать третий столбец `target` - его значения 0 и 1.

Условие записи 1 — нахождение двух или более идентичных строк в таблице, соответственно 0 — отсутствие.
Работаю в Jupyter Notebook, и после использования вот такой вот нехитрой функции блокнот улетает в аут и огромное количество времени "думает":

```
training_set = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

def is_target(columns):
    user_id = columns[0]
    cart = columns[1]

    if len(training_set.loc[(training_set['user_id'] == user_id) & (training_set['cart'] == cart)]) > 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
 
training_set['target'] = training_set[['user_id', 'cart']].apply(is_target, axis=1)
```

Как можно выполнить эту операцию наиболее эффективно? (моя функция вообще не может обработать такое количество данных).

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так. Поскольку у меня нет ваших данных, я формирую свои, случайные (`numpy` тут нужен только для формирования случайных данных).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['user_id','cart']

# создаём случайный датафрейм
n = 3_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(n, 2)), columns=columns)
df = df.sort_values(columns).reset_index(drop=True)

# формирование target
df_count = df.groupby(columns).size().reset_index(name='target')
df_count['target'] = df_count['target'] - 1
df_count.loc[df_count.target > 1, 'target'] = 1
df = df.merge(df_count, on=columns)
```

- группируем данные по интересующим нас колонкам `df.groupby(columns)`
- считаем количество элементов в группе `.size()`
- записываем это число в колонку `target` группировки `.reset_index(name='target')`
- преобразуем `target`, чтобы получилось 0 или 1 по вашей формуле (две следующие строки кода)
- присоединяем колонку target из группировки к основному датафрейму `df.merge(df_count, on=columns)`

Работает в `Google Colab` практически моментально: 3 млн. строк - до секунды, 30 млн. - до 10 секунд, 100 млн. - до 30 секунд, а дальше уже в память упирается, не смог проверить на более больших фреймах.